# How can I Change Button Enabled property when select row in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview

I have DataGridView with some data with it and I have a Button with Enabled property setting to (`False`), I want to do that: when I select row from DataGridView, the Button Enabled property change to (`True`).

I try this code but it don't work, so when I select row from DataGridView the Button Enabled property still (`False`). Help please.

```
Private Sub Form5_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If (Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count <> 0) Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this webforms or winforms?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Looks like WinForms to me.

Comment: @Neolisk Agree. The DataGridView in the code points to Winforms. However, the structure of the code could go either way, and the use of GridView in the prose prompted me to ask for clarification. GridView = WebForms. DataGridView = Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CellClick` Event. Like this.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Don't copy/paste, I just typed it. Check first.

Comment: Thanks adorableVB, I'm try my code with CellClick event and its work well.

Comment: `Button1.Enabled = (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 )`  you can use expressions to skip the IF, especially empty IFs

Comment: didn't know there was something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is WinForms, you want to handle the Grid's [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx) event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    Button1.Enabled = ( DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 )
End Sub
```

If this is WebForms, you want to re-think this. You should use javascript to control it, rather than causing a postback to change the button state. We can do a much better job help you with what javascript might look like if you can tell us a lot more about how the context for this page.